# Identify Bobcat miner component

Tags: diodes, identification

Today I tried to power up my helium bobcat miner with POE.
I used the TP-LINK POE10R PoE Splitter, but after 1 minute the miner turned off and didn't power up anymore... 
I opened the miner and I discovered one component burned with the label "2132 BG". I have already searched for this component but I don't figure out what component it is.
Someone can help me?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Possibly 2132 might mean a component that was manufactured this year in week 32. The BG is the key part to uncovering its identity along with the package size (SMA, SMB, SMC etc) it's probably a diode and quite possibly a TVS diode but, I see no manufacturing logo.

Comment: What on earth is a "helium bobcat miner"?

Comment: @Hearth - not knowing what a "helium bobcat miner" is, I found www.bobcatminer.com and now I still don't know what a "helium bobcat miner" is.

Comment: My understanding from reading about it: HNT (Helium Network Transfer?) is a cryptocurrency. You set up a Wifi network and get "money" for setting up the infrastructure and transferring data. It seems to me like someone wants to build a new telecom infrastructure. It's the logical step: after proof of compute power and proof of storage it now comes to proof of bandwidth. Good luck, Internet.

Comment: It's obviously a Bobcat loader used to mine helium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably a [SMBJ13CA](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) bipolar TVS, assuming it's an SMB

[image]

[image]

Comment: This device is intended to protect against input voltages much higher than about 12V. If you are lucky it may have failed short and prevented further damage.

Comment: I removed the diode, powered up with the original power supply, and fortunately the hotspot working well! I already placed an order to replace this damaged diode.
Thanks a lot!  

Comment: Power over Ethernet is using some >44VDC and this device, judging by the zener voltage, was meant to be powered from 12V.

Comment: @Lundin Also the silk screen “12V” next to the barrel connector center pin.

Comment: Yes, its 12v, but I used this 12v poe splitter: https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/accessory/tl-poe10r/
In theory, it's should be working...